# Build binaries for Linux & Mac via CI

Tags: haskell, build, cabal, haskell-stack

I wrote a Haskell program; I'd rather people not need to have Haskell installed to run it so I want to ship a binary for common platforms (OSX, Linux).

I know that on my computer I can `stack build` or `cabal build` on CircleCI 
to generate a binary; but by default that'll only generate a binary for the OS of the container. How can I build a binary for each of OSX and Linux on either CircleCI (or Travis if necessary)?

Thanks!

Comment: "does this binary run on other platforms or do I need to build a binary for platforms independently?" - yes, of course you must cross compile **binary** files (what is it such a file contains?). To get a GHC cross compiler, you must [build it yourself](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation). With that in mind (building GHC yourself), getting `cabal` or `stack` to use that build is trivial by comparison. (Aside: if you want a program which functions like "golang using ghr", you should explain what that is, instead of forcing readers of this question to learn `go`)

Comment: @user2407038 hrmm, thanks! That helps; I edited the question. I think I might be able to avoid cross-compilation by running two builds via Travis (one on OSX, one on Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get it working for my [Tempered](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/tempered) project. You can check out the [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/tempered/blob/02a9e81251d7947dd6a4b2a9e7303418f23555ea/.travis.yml) file to see how it's done; or check out the blog post I wrote on how to ship binaries via homebrew (it also covers building for linux).

https://chrispenner.ca/posts/homebrew-haskell